Why can't we point a Rust raw pointer to an arbitrary address via pointer arithmetic?
The unsafe method .offset() for raw pointers has the following safety requirement:

If any of the following conditions are violated, the result is Undefined Behavior:

Both the starting and resulting pointer must be either in bounds or one byte past the end of the same allocated object.
...


I am confused about how things could go wrong if a resulting raw pointer points outside of the said bound. I had the impression that if a raw pointer is never dereferenced it is always safe no matter what, because I can create a raw pointer out of thin air with completely safe statements:
let val = 42usize;
let ptr = val as *mut i32;

Is there any example showing that creating a wild pointer through .offset() can crash the program while through casting does not?

There is an explanation as to why the safety requirements are very conservative on offset at the end of it's documentation:

Consider using wrapping_offset instead if these constraints are difficult to satisfy. The only advantage of this method is that it enables more aggressive compiler optimizations.

All emphasis mine
The other method wrapping_offset allows us to arbitrarily offset a pointer. The difference is that

this method basically delays the requirement of staying within the same allocated object. [...] wrapping_offset produces a pointer but still leads to Undefined Behavior if a pointer is dereferenced when it is out-of-bounds of the object it is attached to.

On the other hand,

offset is immediate Undefined Behavior when crossing object boundaries.

The safety requirements are more conservative on offset because

offset can be optimized better and is thus preferable in performance-sensitive code.

So, in principle pointer arithmetics that produce pointers outside of an allocation are safe, you just can't use offset for them.

Thank you for pointing out the wrapping_offset alternative. It seems like offset is indeed performing some optimizations based on the assumptions indicated by the safety requirements. I hope I could get a concrete example if possible.

It's not offset itself that's performing any optimizations, it's the compiler that is allowed to do optimizations based on the safety promises you make when you call it.

Edited: Per Chayim Friedman's comment, UB is likely given any usage of the value returned from an documented-to-cause-UB offset invocation, even simple storage, numeric comparisons, or arithmetic. This is due to rustc's likely use of poison values or equivalent in the return value of documented-UB offset invocations.
I suspect that this is UB-safe, and that the documentation is a bit vague.
Specifically, I think you're right in that the existence or creation of a pointer that is offset outside of a given object is safe (caveat max-size wraparound, which is warned against in the other UB warnings in the pointer::offset docs), but dereferencing it is not.
pointer::offset calls intrinsics::offset, which documents a more specific warning (emphasis mine):

Both the starting and resulting pointer must be either in bounds or one byte past the end of an allocated object. If either pointer is out of bounds or arithmetic overflow occurs then any further use of the returned value will result in undefined behavior.

Even that is still a bit vague; I suspect that it would be valuable to clarify what "use" means. Ideally that would be something like: "dereferencing is UB, arithmetic that risks max-size wraparound is UB, other uses (however rare they may be) are not UB."

This is just wrong. Even if the docs contradict, you should follow the docs of the method you use, since std is free to use stronger assumptions in order to make more cases UB in the future. Add to that the fact that intrinsic docs are often incomplete. And the worst, the docs here do not contradict, offset() compiles to GEP inbounds which returns poison if out of bounds. Poison becomes UB only if used, but "usage" is not defined as you might expect, e.g. even branching on it is UB.

That's good information; I'll edit my answer to reflect that, thanks. Could you provide a source for me to link to re: rustc's LLVM invocation compiling intrinsics::offset to unfrozen GEP output? Additionally, can you expand on "even branching on poison is UB"? The LLVM docs indicate that using a poison value directly as the condition is UB, but I'm not clear on circumstances where that would actually occur: specifically, if poison is icmp'd to something, does poison propagate to the result store of the icmp?

Poison propagates though almost any operation (I think the only exception is freeze), and causes UB on the rest. If you icmp on poison then branch on that, you have UB, because the poison propagated to icmp's result. About Rust, I don't know if this is written down somewhere other than in the compiler's source code, but the important part is not what the compiler does: the important part is that std's docs say that this is UB, so this is UB.
